# service does not return data to controller in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-services

Here is my service:

```
app.service('trackService', ['$http', function($http) {
    var data;
    this.topTracks = function(limit) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gettoptracks',
            params: {api_key: 'e8452c5962aafbb3e87c66e4aaaf5cbf', format: 'json', limit: limit}
        }).success(function(result) {
            this.data = result.tracks; console.log(this.data); return this.data;
        }); 
    }
}]);
```

and controller -

```
app.controller('artistSongsCtrl', ['$scope', 'trackService', function($scope, trackService) {
    $scope.data = trackService.topTracks(10);
    //console.log($scope.data);
}]);
```

how to send data to the controlller using a $http service inside a custom service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several problems are `$http` is asynchronous and your service method  `topTracks()` doesn't return anything. Also you can't return inside `success`, there is nowhere to return to ... use `then()` instead

You need to return the promise from service and set the scope in a promise callback in controller

```
app.service('trackService', ['$http',
  function($http) {
    var data;
    var self = this;
    this.topTracks = function(limit) {
      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gettoptracks',
        params: {
          api_key: 'e8452c5962aafbb3e87c66e4aaaf5cbf',
          format: 'json',
          limit: limit
        }
      }).then(function(result) {
        self.data = result.data.tracks;
        console.log(self.data);
        return self.data;
      });
    }
  }
]);

app.controller('artistSongsCtrl', ['$scope', 'trackService',
  function($scope, trackService) {
    trackService.topTracks(10).then(function(data) {
      $scope.data = data;
      //console.log($scope.data);
    });

  }
]);
```

Comment: .log($scope.data) got error =>  angular.min.js:111 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: Probably didn't do `return $http` in the service as per code shown in asnwer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl I got this, thanks. tell me one thing in the controller, $scope.data is not available outer service. If I want , how?

Comment: function($scope, trackService) {
    trackService.topTracks(10).then(function(data) {
      $scope.data = data;
      //console.log($scope.data); => OK
    });      ////console.log($scope.data); => undefined

Comment: Oooooh ... big problem with `this` inside the service inside the `then()`. See updates using `self`. I should have noticed that before. It is not the same `this` inside any of the callbacks like `success` or `then`

Comment: Also troubleshoot service first ...then controller

Comment: Please help me, I want to use values of $scope.data into another controller.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your service you are making an asynchronous GET request. In order to let the controller catch that response, you need to return a promise. Here's an example using $q:

```
app.service('trackService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
    var data;
    this.topTracks = function(limit) {
        var d = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gettoptracks',
            params: {api_key: 'e8452c5962aafbb3e87c66e4aaaf5cbf', format: 'json', limit: limit}
        }).success(function(result) {
            this.data = result.tracks; 
            console.log(this.data); 
            d.resolve(this.data);
        }); 
     return d.promise;
    }
}]);
```

Comment: This is an anti pattern using `$q` ... `$http` already returns  promise and there is no need to create a new one

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it or https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the link and comment. I do have a question regarding this. What if you need to do some manipulation on the response before resolving? Just as in this example where he wants to store the response in the service + logg it.

Comment: Use `then()` the way I did. Can do any manipulation there. The return in a `then()` is available in the next `then()` in the chain. Note that `$http` docs show `success` as deprecated for this very reason

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks! Just tested it on my code... Good to learn. I will edit my answer and refer to your answer.